# Using subcaption package but subfigures end up stacked rather than side by side

Tags: graphics, subfloats, subcaption

I'm trying to put two jpegs side by side using the subcaption package, but the images are consistently stacking on top of each other rather than side by side. All the solutions I've found simply state that the pictures have to be small enough to actually be side by side but I've tried making them smaller, too small even and they stay stacked. My code looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{inclusion.jpg}
    \caption{inclusions}
    \label{fig:inclu}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{deform}
    \caption{grain deformation}
    \label{fig:deform}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{filler text}
\label{fig:manmade}
\end{figure}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Don't leave blank lines in between (a blank line tantamounts to `\par`, so the next `subfigure` starts a new paragraph), and remove spurious blank spaces (see the `%` after the first `\end{subfigure}`):

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{inclusion.jpg}
    \caption{inclusions}
    \label{fig:inclu}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{deform}
    \caption{grain deformation}
    \label{fig:deform}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{filler text}
\label{fig:manmade}
\end{figure}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{inclusion.jpg}
        \caption{inclusions}
        \label{fig:inclu}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{deform}
        \caption{grain deformation}
        \label{fig:deform}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{filler text}
    \label{fig:manmade}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: Wow, I feel pretty silly now. Thanks so much!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina great point "... remove spurious blank spaces (see the % after the first \end{subfigure} ...". This explains why my attempts to have subfigures each composed of a figure and aligned LaTeX were stacked vertically instead of presented side-by-side as desired.