# subcaption unexpectedly lines up my figures in a column instead of in a row

Tags: graphics, subcaption

I want to set multiple figures in a horizontal row and I tried `subfigure` command of `subcaption` package to do this, referring to the snippet shown at [this site](https://latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/figures/).
However, unexpectedly, the result is the figures are located in a vertical column instead of a horizontal row.

What is wrong?
I'll show a part of my LaTeX code below:

my preamble:

```
\documentclass{jsarticle}

\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm,braket,ascmac}
```

figure section:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{some.jpg}
    \caption{coffee}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{some.jpg}
    \caption{coffee}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{some.jpg}
    \caption{coffee}
  \end{subfigure}
 

  \caption{The same coffees times.}
  \label{fig:coffees}

\end{figure}
```

I'll appreciate for any information.

### Addition

I found I had got a warning below:

```
WARNING
The following warnings have been detected. You can output PDF, but please try to fix them.
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package),
(caption)                standard defaults will be used.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

main.tex
LaTeX Warning: `!h' float specifier changed to `!ht'.

https://texwiki.texjp.org/?LaTeX%20%E3%81%AE%E8%AD%A6%E5%91%8A%E3%83%A1%E3%83%83%E3%82%BB%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8#g0cf562c
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Remove the empty lines between `subfigure` environments in order to get the images to show up side by side. (See also this possible duplicate question: [Using subcaption package but subfigures end up stacked rather than side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162437/134144)) Regarding the warning you quoted, you might want to take a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1527/134144

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I didn't know just inserting the empty lines do something evil.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. Should I discard this question for the duplication?